# Verifiy content of docker image

Tags: docker

A docker container exits when its main process finishes.
In my case, this happens very quickly. The container ends its work faster than I can issue the attach command.

Is there still a way to look at the content of the Docker? For example whether all packages are installed etc. and so on?

```
FROM alpine:3.10
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add \
  curl \
  unzip \
  openssl

# some further stuff
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/curl"]
```

I would like to be able to log into the shell of the container.

Comment: Of course. Have an entrypoint which *doesn't* exit immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you can simply override the entrypoint and spawn a shell inside the container:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh someimage
```

This will work as long as the image actually contains a shell, which is true for the vast majority of images out there.